# What does "no value is acceptable" in Machine Learning hypothesis representation

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to machine learning. I am reading the book, where I have:
– Most general hypothesis
< ? ? ? ? ? ? >
– Most specific hypothesis
< Ø Ø Ø Ø Ø Ø >

in 
Sky AirTemp Humid Wind Water Forecast
< Sunny ? ? Strong ? Same>

I understand that for a learning instance, "?" means it can take on any value, so the outcome of the hypothesis would be 1, as long as the specific attribute is met.

I am confused about "Ø". The book says any value is unacceptable.

Does that mean, if a hypothesis is < ? ? ? ? ? Ø>, no matter what first 5 attributes are, since the last one is unacceptable, the outcome of the hypothesis will be 0?
If so, what is the difference between < ? ? ? ? ? Ø>, and < Ø Ø Ø Ø Ø Ø >?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but unfortunately I'm not sure you would be able to clarify it, since otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right.  Those two hypotheses are equivalent, in that they assign the same classification to every possible instance.  Sometimes there are two different ways to represent the same thing.